# How to override default background color in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, inheritance, background-color, overwrite

My `main.xml` file contains, among others, information about the background color of the app:

```
android:background="@color/background_default"
```

I also have different styles that the user can choose from, saved in other xml files. When the user selects one of those, I want the default values contained in `main.xml` to be overwritten.

Unfortunately, only text color is overwritten, the background color is not changed. Here is one of the custom styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_light</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_light</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just omit `android:background="@color/background_default"` from main.xml, and apply a default theme which uses that color. Then when the user changes the theme the background will change with it.

You can't use a theme to override a color that's specified in view xml; the view is more specific and overrides the theme.

Answer (score 0):

use the parent attribute on your style to inherit the default theme and then override:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Light" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_light</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_light</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: android:Theme does not work, it only overwrites the text color